# Vue-router is not working

Tags: vue.js, vue-router

I am a Vue newbie . I have been trying to setup a simple route using Vue-Router. But i am having a problem which is i dont know why.

I can see the 'Dashboard' message when i go to the url "http://localhost:8080/#/" but i could not see 'Login' when i go to the url "http://localhost:8080/#/login".

Thank you

index.js

```
import Vue from 'vue'
import Router from 'vue-router'
import Dashboard from '@/components/Dashboard'
import Login from '@/components/Login'

Vue.use(Router)

export default new Router({
  routes: [
    {
      path: '/',
      component: Dashboard
    },
    {
      path: '/login',
      Component: Login
    }
  ]
})
```

Login.vue

```
<template>
    <p>Login</p>
</template>

<script>
  export default {}
</script>
```

App.vue

```
<template>
  <div id="app">
    <router-view></router-view>
  </div>
</template>

<script>
export default {}
</script>
```

Dashboard.vue

```
<template>
    <p>Dashboard</p>
</template>

<script>
  export default {
    name: 'Dashboard'
  }
</script>
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I'm not a Vue expert, but I have a feeling you should be navigating to `localhost:8080/login` and not `localhost:8080/#/login`

You've also capitalised `Component` in line 16 of your index.js